# How rails has_secure_password method decides which column to make as password if there is no column named password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

While creating a model, is it possible to have some column name which does not contain text "password" but behave like a password with has_secure_password method?
Like I want my security column to ask for security confirmation

Answer (score 0):

`has_secured_password` adds methods only to set and authenticate against a BCrypt password. If you want to ask for confirmation you can add the `confirm` option to your link. 
Example:

```
 link_to "Create", "http://www.example.org/create", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```